# Plotting arrays from a cell list of strings

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Suppose I have different rows loaded from a .mat file (using `load filename.mat`) containing float numbers following the same naming convention, e.g:

```
file_3try = [ 2.4, 5.2, 7.8 ]
file_4try = [ 8.7, 2.5, 4,2 ] 
file_5try = [ 11.2, 9.11 ]
```

to plot all of these in one plot using automation (I have many more rows than in the example above) I created a cell containing the names of the arrays by using:

```
name{l} = sprintf('%s%02i%s','file_',num,'try');
```

inside a for loop with `num` the numbers in the names and `l` a counter starting from 1.

But when I try to plot the arrays using for example:

```
plot(name{1})
```

I get the error:

```
Error using plot
Invalid first data argument
```

Is there a way to solve this, or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I assume you need to use something like [`eval(name{1})`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), however a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary to be sure.

Comment: You would need `eval`: something like `eval(['plot(' name{1} ')'])`. But using `eval` is not recommended. Better use a cell array or matrix instead of all those variables

Comment: as @LuisMendo says a struct, matrix **or** a struct and plot using dynamic fileldnames

Comment: alright, thanks all! I was just hoping that there was something efficient build-in to solve this, since the data comes from a .mat file like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something built in to solve this

```
data = load ( 'filename' ); % load data and store in struct
fnames = fieldnames ( data );
for ii=1:length(fnames)
  plot ( axHandle, data.(fnames{ii}) );
end
```

`axHandle` is a handle to the axes you want to plot on.  Its not *required* but it is good practice to use it.   If its not provided then the plot command will plot on the current axes, e.g. `gca`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems really like something convenient, but what exactly am I supposed to substitute instead of `axHandle`? Sorry, but this is unclear to me.

Comment: Hi! I've made a chatroom for us so we can discuss things related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or spans longer than what can be placed in a comments box.  Come visit when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Answer (score 2):

So as mentioned already you need to use `eval`.

Assuming the  `file_**X**try` rows are different lengths then you could just place all of them in a cell rather than creating a cell of the variable names. So instead of assigning to separate variables the way you are doing you could assign to a cell, so:

```
file_try{i} =  [.....];
```

You can then cycle through `file_try` and plot each entry:

```
for i = 1:length(file_try)
     plot(file_try{i});
end
```

If the rows are not different lengths then stick them in a matrix and plot it.